# php get with a php session variable

Tags: php, curl, get

I know when using forms you can use POST or GET. I am storing urls in a php session variable. I was wondering if I were to click a link that I have that sends a user to another page of mine, can I use $_GET to grab the necessary link that was clicked.

For example:

```
<?php echo "<a href='myotherpage.php'>".$_SESSION['myvar']."</a>";
```

myvar = "google.com";

So if I were to click that link I want it so it takes me to my other page which uses cURL to scrape the php session (myvar) variable.

Is this possible or is there an easier way for me to go about things?

For those wondering this is what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a mobile version of a forum I visit where the owner does not want to put in the work to make a mobile friendly version. I am creating a mobile friendly version using cURL to fetch the threads and posts.

The answer to the questions above will be assisting me fetch the posts in a thread. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo "<a href='myotherpage.php?my_var=".$_SESSION['myvar']."'>".$_SESSION['myvar']."</a>";
```

Then in $_GET['my_var'] you'll find "google.com"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you might been searching for?

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```